# Can System.Net.Mail.Mailmessage be inherited?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I tried to inherit from mailmessage class, but I can't. 
I want to introduce my own properties in it.

When I type public override , I don't get any override options

here my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace FoodMenu
{
    public class CustomMailMessage:MailMessage
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: From what I can see it's not a final class, you should be able to inherit

Comment: Just because there's no virtual methods doesn't mean you can't inherit from it. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No doubt this class can be inherited as there is no sealed keyword in its declaration.

```
public class MailMessage : IDisposable
```

May be there is no property that can be overrided.

Comment: i guess you mean `sealed` and not `final`